# Recommandation for OOP

Tags: encapsulation

im been learning coding but im kinda stuck at oop. It is hard to comprehend its concept for me. Especially when it comes to encapsuling. Do you know any source that can help me for full understanding oop?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this site explains it well [C++ Encapsulation](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/encapsulation)